# Best approach to store and send android gps location updates continously to a webserver

Tags: android, rest, gps, android-maps

I am making a mobile app to track a target device location on a admin device. For this i am storing the location updates in a PHP-MySQL server and then fetching and displaying it on the admin device.
For this the target device is continuously updating the location table in MySQL database. And admin device is continuously fetching the location table data .

Is there any other way to generated less traffic on MySQL database and sending the location updates directly to admin device using only PHP?

> I just want to know if there is some way to send location updates
>   directly to the other android device, without saving them in web
>   database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not concerned with storing each location in database, then you could have some sort of in memory queue to hold locations and use GCM to send them to admin device.

Check this link https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client to see how gcm can be set up on android ;)

Your server would do something like:

1. receiver POST with new location
2. add location to queue
3. send GCM message to admin device with new location

Comment: we cant store the locations using gcm ?

Comment: I'm afraid not, but you could have both, queue and GCM for instant notification and sending locations to admin device and database to store locations for history purposes.

Comment: can you plz link me any updated tutorial for gcm app server setup ?

Answer (score 2):

Sending continuous location updates is a drain on the battery and also consumes a lot of data. Instead, bunch the requests together. Consider using a [`SyncAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html) to periodically send a bunch of data to your server.

> The sync adapter component in your app encapsulates the code for the
>   tasks that transfer data between the device and a server.

`SyncAdapter` does a lot of the heavy-lifting and error-handling for you. For example, what happens if you couldn't send a location because the network went down? It handles it for you.

Comment: But won't SyncAdapter add delay in real-time updates ?